# Why isnt the session timeout working when set to SqlServer?

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-timeout

I have the line:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;User Id=sa;Password=test;" timeout="1" />
```

Which stores the session in a sql state server. However it does not timeout properly after one minute.

When I change the line to use InProc mode:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;User Id=sa;Password=test;" timeout="1" />
```

It does timeout after one minute.

Any ideas why this is happening? How can I get it to timeout when using SqlServer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server Express, it's because there is no SQL Server Agent to execute the DeleteExpiredSessions procedure.

Here is a possible workaround to the problem:

> In the stored procedure that updates the session, I have added SQL
>   from the DeleteExpiredSessions procedure to the update session stored
>   procedure (I can't remember the name) so it checks for old sessions,
>   deletes the old session, and then updates the current sessions. The
>   stored procedure that updates the session runs on every click anyway,
>   so I added two more lines that remove old sessions before the session
>   is updated. This seems to work fine.

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure the SQL Server Agent service is running
2. Right-click on the SQL Server Agent job named `ASPState_Job_DeleteExpiredSessions` and click "View History" - Make sure this job is running successfully every 1 minute.

In my case, somehow (probably during one of multiple installs involving named instances) my SQL Server Agent had its property `Connection -> Alias Localhost Server` set to just the server name and not the servername\instancename.

When this change happened, the `ASPState_Job_DeleteExpiredSessions` appeared to run indefinitely and could not be stopped.  So, I attempted to re-start the SQL Server Agent service, but it would not start back up.  However, once I changed the `Connection -> Alias Localhost Server` property to servername\instancename, SQL Server Agent started right back up and the `ASPState_Job_DeleteExpiredSessions` job started running successfully once a minute like it should.....and this obviously solved my timeout problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to control the timeout of the session by setting the timeout of the forms authentication cookie:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = 
new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, // version
txtUserName.Text,
DateTime.Now, 
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
false,@"\");
```

That way the user looses contact with the session after 1 min.

Comment: The forms authentication timeout and session timeout are two separate things.