# session variable in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="1" mode="InProc" cookieless="false" >
  </sessionState>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="1"/>
</authentication>
```

i created a session if the user is authenticated like this

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {

        string name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        Session["username"] = name;
    }
```

then i am checking if the session still exit like this

```
  if (Session["username"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("SessionExpired.aspx");
        else
            Response.Write("session still exist");
```

**the problem : **the session is not getting null after 1 min and the user is always login any help

this is the code:

```
     Welcome to ASP.NET! test1
     <p>
     To  visit  test2 go to<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
      onclick="LinkButton1_Click">here</asp:LinkButton> 
     </p>
     <asp:Label ID="msg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

in server side

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {

    string name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
    Session["username"] = name;
    if (Session["username"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("~/SessionExpired.aspx");
    else

 msg.Text = "session still exist the session will be timedout after "+Session.Timeout+ "min";
 }
 else
    Response.Write("please login");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Why isnt the session timeout working when set to SqlServer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122201/why-isnt-the-session-timeout-working-when-set-to-sqlserver) i think this will help you.

Comment: yes. in the link which i posted the user also changed the mode to "inproc"

Comment: that is right and here he is not saying he is got it working fine after changing it to InProc.. He is facing as issue while using it..

Comment: and i'm not using any sql server except the membership database that is by default implemented in asp.net

Comment: the session should time out after 1 min of inactivity. Are you doing any postbacks or any activity?

Answer (score 1):

There is no chance to be  Session["username"] object to null. so if statement useless..

```
string name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
    Session["username"] = name;
    if (Session["username"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("~/SessionExpired.aspx");
```

Comment: how can i check if the session is expired?? if (Session["username"] == null)
isn't that mean if the session variable is expired:o ?

Comment: you can check session expired before assign a value to session. not after. I mean that if statement should be upper than Session["username"] = name; line.

Answer (score 0):

@bassem ala:though you are setting session time out period in configuration file by default asp.net checks servers session time out value.you have to manually set session values null after one minute.